# Keeping an adapted width of an input+button into a fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input, fieldset

I designed some inputs with a button inside of a fieldset, and it seemed a good idea when I worked with fixed width. For example, the width of the input is `205px`, the submit button is `40px` width by using `padding`, `display:block` and `position:absolute`.

But now I use these inputs in different layouts, for example in the footer, with 1, 2, 3 or 4 columns, and I want that the input width adapts getting the full width of the fieldset container, except the width of the submit button.

And this is the HTML structure:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <input type="text" class="field" name="s" placeholder="Buscar">
    <span>
        <input value="" type="submit">
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

I insert the icon using the pseudo-selector `:before` in the `<span>`. So the CSS of the submit button is this:

```
#widget_ID input[type="submit"]{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: transparent;
}
```

I was planning to solve that using `calc(100% - 40px)` in CSS3, but I'm not sure of that because the w3c validator has a bug on this syntax, and I'm making a product which one feature is to be HTML5 valid and CSS3 valid.

So the other solution would be using jQuery. Would you use Javascript to do that? Is it excessive? It would be something like this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on('resize', function(){      

        var w=window,d=document,e=d.documentElement,g=d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],x=w.innerWidth||e.clientWidth||g.clientWidth,y=w.innerHeight||e.clientHeight||g.clientHeight;
        var inputWidth = $('#widget_ID fieldset').width() - 40;

            $('#widget_ID fieldset input').css('width', inputWidth + 'px');

    }).resize();

});
```

What would you do? Thanks in advance :)